# How I can count the SQL Server Service Broker queue processor by sql query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, message-queue, service-broker, messagebroker

I have a no.of custom SQL Server Service Broker queues. I want to monitor the each processor per queue, i.e. how many queue messages were processed per minute in the given Sql server service queue.

Comment: Check this http://blog.extreme-advice.com/2013/02/18/find-service-broker-queue-count-in-sql-server/ and  http://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/gettingfastcountsoflargeservicebrokerqueues

Comment: i check that but i already perform this.. i want simply how many messages receive or send sql server service broker per minute using sql query

Comment: Or how to find number of messages per second that have been put into the queues using sql query.Basically i find the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-broker-statistics-object?view=sql-server-2017 all SQL Server Broker Statistics counters sql queries some queries i findout and some is not